# Move an interrupt handler and variables from main to a include file

Tags: c, global-variables, microcontroller, interrupt

I've a newbie question about how to correctly move an interrupt handler to an include file. I've a SysTick handler in my main.c file defined in this way:

```
volatile int systick_timer_counter = 0;

void SysTick_Handler(void) {
    systick_timer_counter++;
}
```

I use this `systick_timer_counter`, that is increased every 10 ms, to trigger some checks after some time has passed, then reset it.

What I want is to use this `systick_timer_counter` also inside some functions that aren't in my `main.c` file, but in another function's `.c` file. So I want to create a file called `systick_counter` to include where I need to use it.

What I'm asking is, how should I do this in correct way? I can just create a `.c` file and place variable and interrupt header inside it, or should I add something more or change variable definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you mean you want to have a global variable defined in
one module (source file) that’s accessible from other modules.

Assuming I’ve interpreted your question correctly, yes, that can be done
by using the `extern` keyword. However, it would be irresponsible of me
not to say that **using globals unnecessarily is bad practice**. It
results in hard-to-maintain code, because an extern global might be
changed from anywhere in the code base. You want to limit scope and
visibility of your identifiers as much as you can.

In this instance, I would recommend that you instead keep
`systick_timer_counter` local to the module in which it’s defined, and
use functions in that module to access it. It’s like defining a class
with methods, in a language that doesn’t have explicit classes. Doing it
this way, other modules can’t change the value except by calling
`reset_systick()`.

```
int systick_timer_counter = 0;

void reset_systick()
{
    systick_timer_counter = 0;
}

void SysTick_Handler()
{
    systick_timer_counter++;
}

int return_systick()
{
    return systick_timer_counter;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If for example I've in my main a while loop as this "while(return_systick() <= 1000)", that is called with high frequency, it's the same as use a variable or it can create some kind of problems?

Comment: @Singe There’s a little overhead for the function call, but we’re talking about a small number of instructions per call, versus everything else the program is doing. Avoid premature optimization; profile it if you like, but I really doubt it would make a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's also a good idea to add the *static* keyword to variables that you want to only be accessible from within the file.

static int systick_timer_counter = 0;